# Robotium equivalent of drag() in Espresso?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso, robotium

I'm using Espresso to test my application and I need to test a drag n drop behavior in a RecyclerView. Unfortunately I can't see any drag() action in Espresso, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any `Espresso` dragging options. Only `swipeUp()`, `swipeDown()`, `swipeLwft()`,`swipeRight()`, which might be not useful in that case.

Moreover, on Google Groups there is an issue with no answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-test-kit-discuss/X3TDJBUT4Ho/OJAOkTOoxGcJ

Although, there is also `Espresso MotionEvents` class with `sendMovement()` method, but I haven't tried it.

Use the code below:

```
 public static void drag(Instrumentation inst, float fromX, float toX, float fromY,
                            float toY, int stepCount) {
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        float y = fromY;
        float x = fromX;

        float yStep = (toY - fromY) / stepCount;
        float xStep = (toX - fromX) / stepCount;

        MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; ++i) {
            y += yStep;
            x += xStep;
            eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, x, y, 0);
            inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        }

        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        inst.waitForIdleSync();
    }
```

Also read about `TouchUtils`(already deprecated from API 24): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to implement this with MotionEvents, no luck for the moment, but will keep you posted!

Comment: Good to jest that my answer was usefu

Comment: I did not succeed with MotionEvents :( used your code to get the MotionEvent and applied them to a UiController in order to use the code in a custom ViewAction. Needed to add a sleep(1000) after the down as well as my drag n drop is triggered on long press.